# Reversing a string in place in C - pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, reverse

Can someone help me understand what line2:`char * end = str` and line4:`if (str)` do?

```
void reverse(char *str) { 
   char * end = str; 
   char tmp;
   if (str) {
      while (*end) { 
         ++end;
      }
      --end;
      while (str < end) {
         tmp = *str; 
         *str++ = *end; 
         *end-- = tmp;
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if (str)` test protects you from dereferencing a null pointer and crashing.

The definition `char *end = str;` defines the variable `end`, a character pointer, and initializes it with the value stored in `str` (which is the address of the first character of the string that `str` points to).

The rest of the code determines the length of the string, and then arranges to swap pairs of characters from the two ends, working towards the middle of the string.  Technically, the original code is not safe if it is passed an empty string (a pointer that points to the null byte at the end of a string).  That's because it will decrement `end` to one byte before the byte that `str` points at.  However, there is no guarantee that the address one byte before the start of a string is valid.  The string might point to the first byte of a page of memory, and the prior page has never been mapped, leading to crashes or other problems.

It would be better to use `strlen()` to determine the length of the string.

```
void reverse(char *str)
{ 
    if (str != 0 && *str != '\0') // Non-null pointer; non-empty string
    {
        char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1; 

        while (str < end)
        {
            char tmp = *str; 
            *str++ = *end; 
            *end-- = tmp;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: thought that "end"  is set the startng addr of str

Comment: @7-isnotbad: ummm, yes; that's what I said in different words.  The value of `str` is the starting address of the string that `str` points at.

Comment: by "defines the variable end and sets it to the value of str." directed me wrngly...

Comment: `defines the variable end and sets it to the value of str`, although it makes sense, but I would rather say `defines a character pointer, which points to the same contents as the pointer str points to`.

Comment: Your testing for empty string makes sense, but are you sure it would cause problems without it? Code doesn't dereference pointer `end` until it has been tested once when entering the `while` loop. Or is it the comparison of invalid pointer value that is possibly causing problems?

Comment: @user694733 In the case that the string is empty, `end` will point one position before the beginning of the string. Comparing pointers that do not belong to the same array is not guaranteed to work (exception: you can with a pointer to one element past the end of the array)

Comment: Maybe eliminate `&& *str != '\0'` with `char *end = str + strlen(str); while (str<=end) { char t= *str; *str++ = *(--end); *end=t; }`?  Although I suppose this moves away from OP style.

Comment: @chux: there are ways to optimize or reorganize. The key point is not to subtract 1 from the start address of the array as that leads to undefined behaviour.  How you achieve that is up to you. Once we know that the first character is not the null byte, we could add `strlen(str+1)` (with no subtraction).  Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your lovely explanation Jonathan. 

I have a question- What does `char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;` do? 

Why is the `str` necessary? 
Why not just `strlen(str)-1`?

Comment: Using just `strlen(str)-1` would not yield a valid `char *`; I want a valid `char *` so I can compare `str` with it.  You could also write the code in terms of offsets, and the end offset would be `strlen(str)-1`, but it adds to the work that is done compared with using the pointers.  The difference is barely measurable, so it isn't a big issue, but getting the types right is crucial, and `strlen(str)-1` is categorically the wrong type (`size_t`) to be assigned to a `char *`.