# How to change Basys mx3 timer from hex to dec

Tags: c, timer, embedded, hex

i am using Basys mx3, and using the SSDDEMO which function as timer in Hex,
I am trying to change the timer to decimal, with no success.. how do i do that :)?
many thanks,
this is the link to ssddemo:

https://github.com/Digilent/Basys-MX3-library/blob/master/Demos/SSDDemo.X/ssd.c

Comment: The function `SSD_WriteDigitsGrouped()` takes a 32 bit `val` where each byte represents 1 digit.  Tee code does not call this function, so presumably your issue is elsewhere - to be a legitimate SO question to you need to post the relevant code, but the simple answer is that you must encode the `val` argument using _binary coded decimal_ (BCD) rather then binary.  Fix the question by showing how you are calling `SSD_WriteDigitsGrouped()` and including the description of the function from the source comment, then it will be legitimised and answerable.

Comment: Consider this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247647/convert-integer-from-pure-binary-to-bcd

Comment: Note that the code you have linked to is not "a timer", it is a library for displaying on a 4 digit 7-Segment display.  The timer element is used only to multiplex the 4 digits - displaying each one for a short-time very fast in a cycle so it looks as if they are all lit.  The timer aspect is irrelevant to your question and just makes your question confusing and hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In the given library, `SSD_WriteDigitsGrouped()` displays the four hex digits of the `val` argument.  By first converting your integer to [*binary-coded decimal* (BCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) format where each hex nibble represents a decimal digit value 0 to 9, you can display decimal values.

This can easily be done with a wrapper for `SSD_WriteDigitsGrouped()` that does the conversion.  Implement the following function, and call it in place of `SSD_WriteDigitsGrouped()`:

```
void SSD_WriteDigitsGroupedBCD( unsigned int val, unsigned char dp )
{
    unsigned bcd = 0 ;
    int shift = 0 ;

    while( val > 0) 
    {
        bcd |= (val % 10) << (shift << 2) ;
        shift++ ;
        val /= 10;
    }

    SSD_WriteDigitsGrouped( bcd, dp ) ;
}
```